# Turn activemq polling on -> process all messages -> turn off -> wait for a period of time -> repeate

Tags: grails, groovy, activemq-classic, apache-camel

If I have an activemq Camel route definition like

```
from('activemq:some.route')
   .to('direct:some.other.route')
```

Is there a way I can programmatically turn polling for the activemq endpoint on and off in the following fashion: `activemq polling on -> process all messages -> turn off -> wait for a period of time -> repeat`?

Note that I can use quartz for the timing part of it, the main question is whether Camel has a feature which allows me to say "turn on activemq polling, process all messages, then turn off".

Answer (score 0):

You can use two additional routes to start and stop the activemq route. Begin those routes with the timer or quartz component and then call start and stop on the activemq route.

See https://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Christian, but I think I asked the wrong question. What I'm really looking for would be better achieved with help on http://stackoverflow.com/q/13676088/236255 ... there I am using a `ConsumerTemplate` with an ActiveMQ selector (or at least I'm trying), but if I could do something like `from('activemq:some.route?selector=header_timestamp<(sysdate()-(5*60*1000))')` then this question would be perfectly answered!